# Is there a way to return multiple result sets from a single select with joins?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using SQL SERVER and I want something like this:

```
begin
 declare @A, @B

 select A.* into @A, B.* into @B from tableA as A left join tableB as B on 
 A.id = B.id_A

 select distinct * from A
 select distinct * from B
end
```

Note: The sintax I'm using in the example is wrong, I know, it's just because I can't declare a varible of a existing table type to store the results, and I don't know if it's possible to do something to return that kind of result using cursor or something.

I'll be thankfull of any advice.

Note2: I'm trying to use the result in a DataSet, get each table inside, and use this function here to cast it in multiple List for each result (The EF already mapped all the tables).

```
public static class Helper
{
    private static readonly IDictionary<Type, ICollection<PropertyInfo>> _Properties =
        new Dictionary<Type, ICollection<PropertyInfo>>();

    public static List<T> DataTableToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : class, new()
    {
        try
        {
            List<T> list = new List<T>();

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                T obj = new T();

                foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    if (table.Columns.Contains(prop.Name))
                    {
                        if (!row.IsNull(prop.Name))
                        {
                            prop.SetValue(obj, row[prop.Name]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                list.Add(obj);
            }

            return list;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a try to fix performance issues without need to change all the code.

Thank you again.

Comment: This kind of data retrival should be possible if you would use ado.net directly, without entity framework.

Comment: The problem with a DataTable is that all rows must be read. Using a SqlConnection/SqlCommand is better for that. Read row for row with a SqlReader

Comment: I know, but this is an old project, I can't change it now, it's too many things, and possible problems. But thanks for the reply.

Comment: I'm using SqlDataAdapter and filtering the results, I think the DataTable is not a problem now. But thanks, I'll give it a try. 
PS: I need all the columns, the tables are small, but with too many rows.

Comment: datareader would have been far easier as @AlexanderPowolozki said you migt just needed to call Reader.NextResult() thats all